# Adding rows to a datatable with Auto Generated field

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable

Firstly, I have already scoured the interwebs to find the solution but nothing seemed to be exactly right.

I have a DataGrid that is displaying information from my database. I am trying to add records to the datagrid and also the database. The below code is what i have so far for the 'add' button.

```
Dim TaxConnStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Database")
    Dim dbConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(TaxConnStr)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    Try

        dt.Rows.Add(New String() {
                                            boxAssignTo.Text, _
                                            boxState.Text, _
                                            boxCounty.Text, _
                                            boxAmount.Text, _
                                            boxType.Text, _
                                            boxRank.Text})


    Catch ex As Exception
    Finally
        dbConnection.Close()
    End Try
```

Right now I am having the error "Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table." show during this process. I have surmised that it is because in the table on the database I have an autogenerated ID Field that I am not adding to. But i'm clueless on how to add this in.

Dont know if this matters, but when i display the DataGrid i have

```
DataGridView1.Columns.Remove("ID")
```

So i don't physically see the ID field (kinda pointless on this winForm).

Be gentle, i'm very new to databases and VB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because you have not added any columns:

```
    Try
        dt.Columns.Add("a")
        dt.Columns.Add("b")
        dt.Columns.Add("c")
        dt.Columns.Add("d")
        dt.Columns.Add("e")
        dt.Columns.Add("f")

        dt.Rows.Add(New String() {"1","2","3","4","5","6"})


    Catch ex As Exception
    Finally

    End Try
```

Comment: This makes sense now. I assume this won't automatically update my dataGrid, So i should put in my function to obtain the datagrid info after the "finally". Right?

Comment: You would use this when you have a data grid that has no column predefined (Ie in the form view).  If the grid is already created and you are just adding values to it, you need to do it another way.  Is this ASP.net or a windows form?

Comment: Windows form. The datagrid is reading the column info from a Database table. I'm just trying to update the datagrid and the DB table.

Comment: Once you create a data table and fill it with data rows, you can bind it to the data grid, like this:  Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

Comment: Ok all of this has worked so far. The dataGrid is updating just fine with the new criteria that i'm trying to add. However, it is not updating to the database...Also, whenever i do click the 'add' (button all this code is for), the datagrid is not updated...it is just overwritten with the new information. How can i just add to the datagrid and not completely re-do it